# Invoke an Overloaded Constructor through this?

Tags: c#-4.0, c#-3.0

i can't understand this paragraph and i don't know , what does mean term INVOKE in programming?

When working with overloaded constructors, it is sometimes useful for one constructor to
invoke another. In C#, this is accomplished by using another form of the this keyword.

Comment: It is a synonym for "call", usually in an indirect way.

Answer (score 0):

In this context invoke is equivalent to call. In C# Invoke usually refers to calling a method in a thread-safe way. Very useful for GUI-development and basically everywhere else as well.